# Python - Export a Matplotlib plot to KML file

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to code below, which reads a file of (geographic) coordinates (longitudes, latitudes), computes a minimum spanning tree from a distance matrix among these points and plots the resulting tree using Matplotlib.

```
import warnings
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import simplekml

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def minimum_spanning_tree(X, copy_X=True):
    """X are edge weights of fully connected graph"""
    if copy_X:
        X = X.copy()

    if X.shape[0] != X.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError("X needs to be square matrix of edge weights")
    n_vertices = X.shape[0]
    spanning_edges = []

    # initialize with node 0:                                                                                        
    visited_vertices = [0]                                                                                           
    num_visited = 1
    # exclude self connections:
    diag_indices = np.arange(n_vertices)
    X[diag_indices, diag_indices] = np.inf

    while num_visited != n_vertices:
        new_edge = np.argmin(X[visited_vertices], axis=None)
        # 2d encoding of new_edge from flat, get correct indices                                                     
        new_edge = divmod(new_edge, n_vertices)
        new_edge = [visited_vertices[new_edge[0]], new_edge[1]]                                                      
        # add edge to tree
        spanning_edges.append(new_edge)
        visited_vertices.append(new_edge[1])
        # remove all edges inside current tree
        X[visited_vertices, new_edge[1]] = np.inf
        X[new_edge[1], visited_vertices] = np.inf                                                                    
        num_visited += 1
    return np.vstack(spanning_edges)

def test_mst():
    P = np.loadtxt("testdata.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

    X = squareform(pdist(P))

    edge_list = minimum_spanning_tree(X)
    plt.scatter(P[:, 0], P[:, 1], c='b')

    edges = []
    for edge in edge_list:
        i, j = edge
        plt.plot([P[i, 0], P[j, 0]], [P[i, 1], P[j, 1]], c='b')
        edges.append([(P[i, 0], P[j, 0]), (P[i, 1], P[j, 1])])
    plt.show()

    # Save KML file
    kml = simplekml.Kml()
    for i in range(len(edges)):
        line = kml.newlinestring(name="Track" + str(i + 1), coords=edges[i])
        line.style.linestyle.width = 3
        line.style.linestyle.color = simplekml.Color.red
    kml.save("mst.kml")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_mst()
```

And here is my test data:

```
Longitude,Latitude
-61.05,10.4
-79.4333333333,9.15
-70.6666666667,9.5333333333
-63.1166666667,7.9166666667
-63.1166666667,10.55
-81.1833333333,7.5166666667
-56.4833333333,3.1
-60.5,3.9333333333
-81.0166666667,7.6666666667
-67.4333333333,8.9333333333
-65.9666666667,10.3166666667
-78.9333333333,8.3833333333
-72.8666666667,9.8333333333
-68.4,10.6166666667
-72.9833333333,10.6166666667
```

It works fine and shows the plot below:

[image]

However, I also want to save the coordinates of the resulting tree into a KML format for plotting it using Google Earth. I am then storing the same coordinates passed to construct the plot into a list of tuples, which I then pass to a [simpleKml](http://www.simplekml.com/) object. It does not work and the tree is not correctly displyed by Google Earth.

So, in general terms, my question is: how could I save (in whatever format) the coordinates of the plot, in order to be able to reconstruct it exactly as it is displayed by Matplotlib?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

EDIT: Below is the KML file as it appears in Google Earth:

[image]

And here is how it *should* appear (this plot was created using Matplotlib and Basemap):

[image]

Comment: What does "It does not work" mean? What is the output and what's wrong with it?

Comment: It means the tree is not plotted. What appears in Google Earth is a gibberish plot of displaced lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the simplekml documentation](http://simplekml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gettingstarted.html#creating-a-linestring), coordinates need to be given as pairs of `(lon,lat)`.

So instead of

```
 # edges.append([(P[i, 0], P[j, 0]), (P[i, 1], P[j, 1])])
```

you need

```
 edges.append([(P[i, 0], P[i, 1]), (P[j, 0],P[j, 1] )])
```

Screenshot of google earth:

[image]

Comment: Interleaving, that is it! How stupid I was! Thank you *very much*, @ImportanceOfBeingErnes! You are great.

Answer (score 1):

The only other option would be to convert to a .csv then an xml

https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/csvtokml

 
Not sure if this was what you are looking for

Comment: It does not works this way. The plt.savefig function is intended to save only images, kml is a structured text file (indeed, a xml file with some special tags).

Comment: thank you too1 Although the above answer solved my problem, your suggestion may (and will!) surely be useful to me on other occasions.